# angularjs controller pass function to directive in a directive with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, function, hierarchy, directive

Has anybody tried to pass a parent controller function to an inner directive(directive inside a directive)?

here is how I am trying to do it(, I have eliminated lines that are not relevant):

```
angular.module('myHeaven').controller('forrestController',function($scope)
{
    $scope.notifyCallback=function(notificationData){
        console.log('It is Adam again: ' & notificationData);
    }
});

angular.module('myHeaven').directive('tree',function($scope){
    return {
        scope:{notification:'&'}
    }
});

angular.module('myHeaven').directive('apple',function($scope){
return {
    scope:{
     notification:'&'
    },
    template:'<input type="button" ng-click="pick()" >bite Me</button>'
    controller:function($scope){
    $scope.pick=function(){
     $scope.notification({notificationData:'apple picked'});    
    }
 }
}
});
```

heaven.html

```
<div tree notification="notifyCallback(notificationData)">
    <div apple notification="notifyCallback(notificationData)">
    </div>  
</div>
```

The $scope.notification in forrestController is called but no parameters are passed.

Comment: Where have you defined "notificationData" before using in <div tree notification="notifyCallback(notificationData)">

Comment: correction: template is actually templateUrl but the contents are <input type=button click="pick()">bite Me</button>

Comment: @Yashika: this is a special angular Syntax. <directive passed-function="thefunc(myData)"></directive> and from directive.js you call passedFunction({myData:'some string'});

Comment: That is what I was asking from where are you calling it like this: passedFunction({myData:'some string'});

Comment: @Yashika: I have added a comment.. it is called from the apple directive. it is a button click="pick()"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use transclusion on the tree directive or you could write the other directive inside the template of the tree.
You don't need to pass the method to the tree directive as long as you use transclusion on it.
and you where passing $scope into the directive factory function, this was causing an error. Pass $scope on the controller. On the directive scope is passed as the first parameter of the link function.
Check out my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GVbr2bCiGNbPN0kkKoha?p=preview):

```
  <div tree >
    <div apple notification="notifyCallback(notificationData)"></div>  
  </div>


angular.module('myHeaven', []);

angular.module('myHeaven')
      .controller('forrestController',function($scope) {
          $scope.notifyCallback=function(notificationData) {
              console.log('It is Adam again: ' + notificationData);
    };
});

angular.module('myHeaven').directive('tree',function(){
    return {
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div class="tree"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
        scope:{}
    };
});

angular.module('myHeaven').directive('apple',function(){
return {
    scope:{
     notification:'&'
    },
    template:'<input ng-click="pick()" type=button>bite Me</button>',
    controller:function($scope){
    $scope.pick=function(){
     $scope.notification({notificationData:'apple picked'});    
    };
 }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer,.. just a syntax.

```
<div tree notification="notifyCallback({notificationData:notificationData})">
    <div apple notification="notifyCallback({notificationData:notificationData})">
    </div>  
</div>
```